# What is the dask equivalent of numpy where?

Tags: python, dask

I am trying to do the equivalent of the following vectorized if-else, but could not find anything that worked for dask. (`dask.array.where` always returns `NotImplemented`)

What is the best way to accomplish this?

`np.where(df['columne'] > 0, 0, 1)`

Comment: What if you just assign the result directly? I.e. `df["columne_bool"] = (df["columne"] <= 0).astype(int)`

Comment: @alkasm your solution is definitely a workaround. I do have use cases like this though darray.where(df['col'] < 1e-3, np.nan, df['col2'])

Comment: You can still just assign values in each case `where` is used, you just have to turn it into two assignments. First assign the value for the false condition, and then conditionally assign the true value. `df['new'] = val_when_false` and `df[condition, 'new'] = val_when_true`.

Comment: As @alkasm, your usage of `where` is unnecessary to begin with.

Answer (score 5):

The Dask equivalent of `numpy.where` **is** `dask.array.where`.

As an example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
​
import dask.array as da
import dask.dataframe as dd
​
df = pd.DataFrame([-1,2,-4,5,-10], columns=['a'])
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, 2)
print(df)
    a
0  -1
1   2
2  -4
3   5
4 -10
```

```py
da.where(ddf['a'] > 0, 0, 1).compute()
array([1, 0, 1, 0, 1])
```

You could also do the equivalent example from your comment.

```py
da.where(ddf['a'] > 0, np.nan, 5*ddf['a']).compute()
array([ -5.,  nan, -20.,  nan, -50.])
```

You may need to upgrade your library versions, install additional libraries (such as dask.array), or provide more information if your specific example is not working. This works with the following Dask libraries installed:

```
dask                      2.10.0                     py_0  
dask-core                 2.10.0                     py_0
```

Comment: It's worth noting that Dask Dataframes also have a `.where` method if you want to keep the Series structure rather than switch to arrays.